# Transferring memory space fro Drive C: to Drive D:

Tags: partitioning, partition

I am having a difficulty on finding how am i going to transfer memory space from c: to D:.

I don't know why my drive c: has 444  GB and my drive D: has only 19.4 GB , I don't know if it's good or bad to have that kind of partition but now my D: is so bloody. HAHA

Pls help/guide me to transfer space or make changes in the partition of my Disks without negative changes on my laptop. There's no Unallocated space.

But I have here a screenshot of my Disk mgmt. I'm glad for your positive response. Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osoyx.png)

Comment: This site is for programming questions - not general tech support.

Comment: If you're looking for some tech support go to something like this: https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/

Comment: Or superuser ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its good you've already opened Disk Mgmt. Just right click on the C: Partition there and you will get an option named "Shrink". Click on it and enter the Amount of Space you want to take out from Drive C:. After you are done, Right click on the D: Partition in the Disk Management and click Extend, You should then enter the amount of space you want to extend your partition to.

Congrats :) you saved your D:

But you should Keep in mind next time that this site is for programming questions and for tech support you should go for other support sites.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I'll try this one. ^^

Comment: Hey, last question. HAHA will it affect my files(will it be deleted) if i directly partitioned it? Thanks again. :)

Comment: you can't perform direct partitioning without any free space, however you have to delete the space to perform direct partitioning, which will Seriously delete your Files,,

Thats why I recommended Shrink and Extend Methods. :)